# How to place legend inside caption area on R

Tags: r, legend, caption

I am using R studio / R Markdown to create plots, some with ggplot, some with base R function. I would like to insert a caption for each of my plots which contains the legend similar to the example shown here:

[image]

Can anyone suggest how to place the legend of my plots (built with ggplot and base R functions) within the caption as shown in this example?

I searched online and found out that it is possible to use something like:

```
p +  labs(caption="Figure S1: This is the Figure Legend")
```

however, I could not find how to embed the legend into the caption, and I also could not find a solution for plots made using base R.

There are some solutions that require Latex, but I cannot use Latex for this project.

Comment: What are you using to generate the caption? Are you knitting a document in html, or in LaTex, or are you using sweave?

Comment: I am using R Markdown with knit to Word.

Comment: Ok, and what have you searched? Which options, configuration, and other related information have you found? If you provide more relevant information it will be easier to get help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just push the legend to the bottom and add a custom title - inlcude a counter to get numbered Plots:

```
library(ggplot2)
# using the internal iris dataset
iris
# set counter to zero
NR <- 0

# Add counter and build plot
NR <- NR + 1
legend <- paste0("Fig. ", NR, ": This is a Plot about...:")
ggplot2::ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Petal.Width, color = Species)) +
  ggplot2::geom_point() +
  ggplot2::labs(color= legend) +
  ggplot2::theme(legend.position = "bottom")


# Add counter and build second plot
NR <- NR + 1
legend <- paste0("Fig. ", NR , ": This is a Plot about...:")
ggplot2::ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, color = Species)) +
  ggplot2::geom_point() +
  ggplot2::labs(color= legend) +
  ggplot2::theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```